# Unity 2D, Prefab text with rising animation is spawned on touch, correct x position but always spawns at y 0?

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, mobile, 2d, touch

The bonus text particle has an animation where it is at x 0 the whole time, but the y rises from 0 to 1.
When playing the game, tapping the screen, the particle is created at the correct finger position x level but is always starts at y 0 instead of the finger position in y.

I want it to spawn at the exact finger position. I think it's because of the animation but I have no idea how to fix it.

[screen recording](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pKswn3gQWGrB8iamEx6_npV8IE3P2alb/view?usp=sharing)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using BreakInfinity;
using UnityEngine.Pool;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Stats")]
    public static BigDouble notes = 0;
    public static BigDouble tap = 10;
    public static BigDouble auto = 0;

    [Header("Taps")]
    [SerializeField] private GameObject bonusParticlePrefab;

    float tapCooldown = 0.04f;
    float lastTapTime = 0f;

    private ObjectPool<GameObject> bonusParticlesPool;

    void Start()
    {
        bonusParticlesPool = new ObjectPool<GameObject>(CreateFunction, ActionOnGet, ActionOnRelease, ActionOnDestroy);
    }

    private GameObject CreateFunction()
    {
        return Instantiate(bonusParticlePrefab, transform);
    }

    private void ActionOnGet(GameObject bonusParticle)
    {
        bonusParticle.SetActive(true);
    }

    private void ActionOnRelease(GameObject bonusParticle)
    {
        bonusParticle.SetActive(false);
    }
    
    private void ActionOnDestroy(GameObject bonusParticle)
    {
        Destroy(bonusParticle);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        foreach(Touch touch in Input.touches)
        {
            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            {
                if (Time.time - lastTapTime > tapCooldown)
                    {
                        bool isOverUI = false;
                        for (int i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; i++)
                        {
                            if (EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject(Input.GetTouch(i).fingerId))
                            {
                                isOverUI = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        if (!isOverUI) // if not over UI elements
                        {
                            IncreasePoints();
                            Vector3 touchPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position);
                            touchPosition.z = 0;

                            lastTapTime = Time.time; // Update the last tap time 

                            GameObject bonusParticleInstance = bonusParticlesPool.Get();
                            bonusParticleInstance.transform.position = touchPosition;

                            LeanTween.delayedCall(1, ()=> bonusParticlesPool.Release(bonusParticleInstance));
                        }
                        
                    }
            }
        }
    }

    void IncreasePoints()
    {
        notes += tap;        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the animation of rising particles on the **y axis** is done with animator and animation we can deduct that this is the reason why your `touchPosition` is being ignored when you get the particle from the pool.

You are spawning the particle at the `touchPosition` but it's immediately told by the animation to move from **0** to **1** on the y axis.

To fix this, I would avoid using animation for animating the bonusParticle because you want to dynamically tell the particle to move from **y** to **y + 1** and that dynamic behavior is not possible with pure animation (from what I know).

You can use the LeanTween library to do that:

```
GameObject bonusParticleInstance = bonusParticlesPool.Get();
bonusParticleInstance.transform.position = touchPosition;

LeanTween.moveY(bonusParticleInstance, touchPosition.y + 1f, 1f);
```